# How to update column with if-else-if condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL Server and on the learning phase. I wanted to perform following task.

I have two table Table1 and Table2. I want to loop the row of Table1 to check if value matches with any row of Table2.

Table1:

```
ID    Name    Nationality   DOB     Priority
--------------------------------------------
1     Sujan    Nepali       1996     NULL
2     Sujan    Nepali       1999     NULL
3     Sujan    Chinese      1996     NULL
4     Sujan    Chinese      1888     NULL
```

Table 2:

```
ID    Name    Nationality   DOB     Address    Rank
---------------------------------------------------
1     Sujan    Nepali       1996    Kathmandu   1
```

In Table1 with ID 1 matches all value of same column name in Table2. I need to Update priority of it as 1.

In ID 2 DOB is different and Name and Nationality matches so Update priority as 2.

In ID 3 Name and Year is same as of Table2, so Update priority as 3.

In ID 4 only Name is same, so Update priority as 4.

Expected Output:

Table1:

```
ID    Name    Nationality   DOB     Priority
---------------------------------------------
1     Sujan    Nepali       1996     1
2     Sujan    Nepali       1999     2
3     Sujan    Chinese      1996     3
4     Sujan    Chinese      1888     4
```

I have used CASE but need to perform using IF ELSE IF condition. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show expected output.

Comment: `IF` is a logical flow operator in T-SQL; you can't use it within a `SELECT` statement. You do have `IIF` however. [Logical Functions - IIF (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql). It is, however, just a short hand for a `CASE` expression though. So `IIF(NameField = 1, FullName, CompanyName)` is identical to `CASE WHEN NameField = 1 THEN FullName ELSE CompanyName END`.

Comment: The "and so on" needs more detail.

Comment: @dfundako I have updated the question.

Comment: @shawnt00 I have updated the question

Comment: `but need to perform using IF ELSE IF` - that is exactly what CASE can do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this. Cross join two tables and look for columns that match each other. According to that make updates.

```
declare @table1 table (ID int, Name varchar(100), Nationality varchar(100), DOB int, Priority int)
insert into @table1
values 
(1, 'Sujan', 'Nepali', 1996, NULL)
, (2, 'Sujan', 'Nepali', 1999, NULL)
, (3, 'Sujan', 'Chinese', 1996, NULL)
, (4, 'Sujan', 'Chinese', 1888, NULL)

declare @table2 table (ID int, Name varchar(100), Nationality varchar(100), DOB int, Address varchar(100), Rank int)
insert into @table2 values (1, 'Sujan', 'Nepali', 1996, 'Kathmandu', 1)

;with cte as (
select 
    a.*, rnk = row_number() over (order by case when a.Name = b.Name then 100 else 0 end
    + case when a.Nationality = b.Nationality then 10 else 0 end
    + case when a.DOB = b.DOB then 1 else 0 end desc)
from
    @table1 a
    join @table2 b on a.Name = b.Name
)

update cte
set priority = rnk

select * from @table1
```

Here's a [rextester demo](http://rextester.com/XUN70045)

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is homework I see no reason to use `if` constructs.

```
update table1 set priority = (
    select min(case
            when table2.id = table1.id and ... then 1
            when ... then 2
            when ... then 3
            ...
        end
    from table2
)
```

Just make sure the branches go in order of highest to lowest priority.

Comment: as I mention in the question, it is a task. I am taking training program and been stuck on this for 4 days now.